# insertion in linked list -

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I was reading Skeina's book. I could not understand this code. Basically what is the use of double pointer. And what is the use of `*l = p`? Can anyone please explain by diagram.

```
void insert_list(list **l, item_type x) {
    list *p; /* temporary pointer */
    p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = x;
    p->next = *l;
    *l = p;
}
```

Comment: This is not C++ (cannot use `malloc` without casting, should use smart pointers in C++ or `new` if you must use raw pointers).

Comment: @VladfomMoscow Does c work without the `struct` keyword nowadays?

Comment: @crashmstr: you don't need to cast results of malloc in C.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Yes it works if you will use a typedef.:)

Comment: @rost0031 I know that and I did not say that you needed to cast the results in C. I said that since there was no casting of `malloc`, *it could not be C++*, which was how it was originally tagged.

Comment: @crashmstr: sorry, I misunderstood your meaning since the question was already tagged correctly by the time I looked at it.

Comment: help i am struct.new to programming

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call it a "double pointer" because that would be a pointer to a `double`.  It is a pointer to a pointer, and it is used to allow the function to alter the value of an argument which happens to be a pointer.  If you're familiar with C#, it's like an `out` argument.  In this situation the `l` argument used to get both IN and OUT behavior, but you may often see this used for output only.

Since this function returns type `void` it very well could have been written without the use of the pointer to a pointer like this:

```
list * insert_list(list *l, item_type x) {
{
    list *p; /* temporary pointer */
    p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = x;
    p->next = l; // note that this is not *l here
    return p;
}
```

This change would require the code that calls the function to update it's own handle to the list since the head of the list is what's being changed.

Answer (score 0):

This function performs a very simple task: it inserts a `list` node at
the position for which it receives a pointer.  There is nothing
special about *double pointers*, they are just pointers to pointers.  They hold the address of a pointer, which contains the address of an object.
`void **l` contains the address of a `list *` pointer. `*l` retrieves
this address and `*l = p` stores it.

`malloc` is used to allocate a
`list` structure, `p` receives the address of the allocated structure.
The code is somewhat sloppy as `p` is not checked for `NULL` before
dereferencing it.  If `malloc` fails because of lack of memory, the
program will invoke undefined behaviour, hopefully stopping with a
segmentation fault or something potentially worse.

The node is initialized, its `next` pointer is set to the node pointed
to by the `l` argument, and finally the new node's address is stored
at the address passed as the `l` argument.  The effect is simple: the node is inserted at `*l`.

This method is clever ad it allows the same function to insert a new node anywhere is a list. For example:

```
list *head = NULL;
...
/* Insert a LIST_A node at the beginning of the list */
insert_list(&head, LIST_A);
...
/* insert a LIST_B element as the second node in the list */
insert_list(&head->next, LIST_B);
...
/* find the end of the list */
list *node;
for (node = head; node->next; node = node->next)
    continue;

/* insert a LIST_Z node at the end of the list */
insert_list(&node->next, LIST_Z);
```

The only tricky thing above is the concept of pointer itself, here is a simple overview:

- Memory can be conceptualized as a (large) array of bytes, addresses are offsets in this array.
- `char` variables by definition are single bytes,
- `int` variables occupies a number of bytes specific to the architecture of the system, typically 4 or 8 bytes in current hardware.
- Think of pointers as variables holding the address in memory of another variable. They need to be large enough to hold any valid address in the system, in current systems with more than 4 GB of physical and addressable memory, they are 64 bit long and occupy 8 bytes.
- There is a special address value `NULL` which represents no object and is used to specify that a given pointer does not point to any real object. The address `0` is used for this purpose. `malloc` will return `NULL` if it cannot allocate the memory requested, the return value should be tested, as storing a value at this address is forbidden and usually caught as an invalid access (segmentation fault).

This summary is purposely simplistic.  I used the term *variable* instead of *object* to avoid the confusion with OOP concepts.

Comment: @blue boy: the *correct* way to thank responders is to upvote their answers and to accept the most helpful one.